# Angular 2: Dynamically setting NgStyle and NgClass

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically set the style of the img element by calling a function in the component that sets a component property to the target style. But it is not working.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
          <a (click)="setColor('Black')">
          <img class="img-fluid {{blackImgClass}}" 
            src="../assets/images/4ade25d4-3c31-45bd-a1e3-063b9f46c3d1_35.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 color-selection">
          <a (click)="setColor('Stainless Steel')">
          <img class="img-fluid {{stainlessImgClass}}" 
            src="../assets/images/62167c88-bf89-4848-acd6-c74d1970312a_35.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 color-selection">
          <a (click)="setColor('White')">
          <img class="img-fluid color-white {{whiteImgClass}}" 
            src="../assets/images/c79cd82b-37ea-43c4-b3ea-daceb08c4267_35.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
```

The class is set in the component in this function:

```
private setColor(color: string) {
if (color == 'Black') {
  this.productImages = this.product.images.black;
  this.currentImage = this.product.images.black[0];
}
else if (color == 'White') {
  this.productImages = this.product.images.white;
  this.currentImage = this.product.images.white[0];
}
else if (color == 'Stainless Steel') {
  this.productImages = this.product.images.stainless;
  this.currentImage = this.product.images.stainless[0];
}

this.setCSSClass(color);
  }
```

And the setCSSClass():

```
private setCSSClass(color) {
if (color == 'Black') {
  this.whiteImgClass = '';
  this.blackImgClass = 'border-bottom: 3px solid #f96302';
  this.stainlessImgClass = '';
  this.selectionColor = color;
}
else if (color == 'White') {
  this.whiteImgClass = 'border-bottom: 3px solid #f96302';
  this.blackImgClass = '';
  this.stainlessImgClass = '';
  this.selectionColor = color;
}
else if (color == 'Stainless Steel') {
  this.whiteImgClass = '';
  this.blackImgClass = '';
  this.stainlessImgClass = 'border-bottom: 3px solid #f96302';
  this.selectionColor = color;
}
```

}

Comment: could you create plunkr template?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `class` twice, one of which is going to be ignored. I'm also not sure if binding class with interpolation will work.

I'd simplify the css first, since all three images styles share some basic properties - and then just use `[ngStyle]` to set the color and any other css properties you need to.

HTML

`<img class="img-fluid basic-image-class" src="../assets/images/c79cd82b-37ea-43c4-b3ea-daceb08c4267_35.jpg"
[ngStyle]="currentImageStyles">`

CSS

`.basic-image-class: {border-bottom: 3px solid;}`

Code

```
public currentImageStyles: string = '';

private setCSSClass(color) {
if (color == 'Black') {
  this.currentImageStyles = {'border-bottom-color: #f96302'};
}
else if (color == 'White') {
  this.currentImageStyles = {'border-bottom-color: #999'};
}
else if (color == 'Stainless Steel') {
  this.currentImageStyles = {'border-bottom-color: #ccc'};
}
```

Comment: I think - code need some correction. I've tried below code in my Angular-7 Project.
currentImageStyles: any ={}; 
this.currentImageStyles = {"border-bottom-color": "#ccc"};

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this - I set dynamically top value to my absolute elment, and I do it with [style.top.px]="top" , top is a variable in my typescript that gets a number after I calculate its value. Just set what u wish there

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well, you need to update your html to:

```
      <img class="img-fluid color-white" 
      src="../assets/images/c79cd82b-37ea-43c4-b3ea-daceb08c4267_35.jpg"
      class="color-white" [class.white-class]="yourCondition">
```

Where "yourCondition" should return true when you want to add "white-class" and false when you don't.

In your css:

```
image.white-class{
    //DO your stuff
}
```

For multiple classes binding you can use ngClass as mentioned below:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass